# How to use match function to match two values from a sheet with another sheet and get the result?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two values in a sheet "SheetA"

SheetA:

```
Column A      Column B
Apple         10.5
```

I want this two values to be matched with sheet "SheetB" and get the answer from Column C "Done"

SheetB:

```
Column A   Column B   Column C
Apple      10         Undone
Apple      10.5       Done
```

Using match function I tried

```
mav = Evaluate("INDEX(SheetB!$C$1:$C$5,MATCH(A1 & B1,SheetB!$A$1:$A$5&SheetB!$B$1:$B$5,0))")

Msgbox mav
```

I receive:

> Error 2042

Please help me on this. This is an example. I wanted to use this formula in my code once I get a solution. Thanks in advance.

When I refer the values with same sheet like below it is working.

```
mav = Evaluate("INDEX($C$1:$C$5,MATCH(A1 & B1,$A$1:$A$5&$B$1:$B$5,0))")
```

When I refer it to different sheet, it is not working.

```
mav = Evaluate("INDEX(SheetB!$C$1:$C$5,MATCH(A1 & B1,SheetB!$A$1:$A$5&SheetB!$B$1:$B$5,0))")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the `=` character:

```
mav = Evaluate("=INDEX(SheetB!$C$1:$C$5,MATCH(A1 & B1,SheetB!$A$1:$A$5&SheetB!$B$1:$B$5,0))")
```

Other than that error 2042 equals `#N/A` so maybe you have made a bad sheet reference. With correct references the code works fine, see below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

What's also nice to note; this actually is an array formula, but in VBA you only need the string value of the formula :)

Comment: I've always found Evaluate to work equally well (no pun intended) with or without the `=` sign.

Comment: @user11246173, yes it does. Was hoping it would make a difference. It doesn't so only option is that OP has a mistake made in sheet references I guess

Comment: Sheet name is correct. i don't know how to refer it correctly in the above formula. I have tried it giving quotes, still not working.. :(

Comment: @Mohamed_Ebu, according to your own question you have done nothing wrong. Please make sure that your `SheetB` is actually called `SheetB`! :)

Comment: when i use match function matching one value in different sheet, it is working fine. when i combine 2 values and referring it to different sheet, it is not working.

Comment: Using your example works perfectly fine for me and returns the correct value. Your error comes from a wrong reference so make sure your data actually equals the setup you used in your question. Can't you provide a print screen of your data in the question?

Comment: Try it with all the worksheets properly referenced. `Evaluate("INDEX(SheetB!$C$1:$C$5, MATCH(SheetA!A1&SheetA!B1, SheetB!$A$1:$A$5&SheetB!$B$1:$B$5, 0))")` works for me.

Comment: Thank you both for your valuable comments. it works fine now. data mismatched between sheets while trying to figure out the issue. It works fine now after rechecking it reading your comments. thanks again. :)

Comment: @Mohamed_Ebu, no problem. Glad you got your code working. If this has been helpfull/answered your question. Please consider marking your question as answered.